# How to identify and track multitouch gestures in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, uigesturerecognizer, multi-touch, event-tracking

There is a lot of documentation about tracking multitouch gestures in React Native, but almost nothing for React.js. Is it recommended to use a library? if it is, which one? I want to identify and track gestures like pinch, pan, swipe, zoom.